# MySQL Query based on user input in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, user-input

i'm new to SQL and Java and couldn't find anything to fix my problem.
(closest thing: [MySQL query based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715193/mysql-query-based-on-user-input))
So I have a DB full of shows/events and I want users to "search" for a certain event or show.
The user will input the name of the show/event into GUI and I want the query to return data associated with the user-input.

For example:

User is searching for the artist Zedd;

```
searchSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT eventname,date FROM shows WHERE artist LIKE      'zedd' ");
```

The query is fixed, can the query be modified to search whatever the user input?

Something like:

```
String artist = "zeppelin"
searchSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT eventname,date FROM shows WHERE artist LIKE "artist" ");
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: careful with sql injection and check sql like wildcards

Answer (score 3):

You should double check your shows second column. I'm not sure you can use a column named `date`. Anyway, you should certainly use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) with something like,

```
String sql = "SELECT eventname, eventdate FROM shows WHERE artist LIKE ?";
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  ps.setString(1, artist);
  rs = ps.executeQuery();
  while (rs.next()) {
    String eventName = rs.getString("eventname");
    Date eventDate = rs.getDate("eventdate");
    // Use your columns in your row here.
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (rs != null) {
    try {
      rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  if (ps != null) {
    try {
      ps.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure that `WHERE artist = ?` is right, shouldn't it be `WHERE artist LIKE ?`?? - Otherwise, yes, that's the way it should be done ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Edited. I got distracted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
String artist = "zeppelin"
searchSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT eventname, date FROM shows WHERE artist LIKE '%" + artist + "%'");
```

Note the sql wildcard string '%'

Comment: single quotes also work nicely and do not need escaping

Comment: @ScaryWombat Agree. It is a good point. Actually the double quote will cause sql failure if the target db is MSSQL. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per normal SQL, you statement would work if it was

```
String artist = "'%zeppelin%'";
searchSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT eventname,date FROM shows WHERE artist LIKE " +  artist);
```

The String needs to be aurrounded with `%` and also quoted.

Have a look at [preparedStement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) though, it has method to set each parameter separately and avoid SQL injection.